# Subdocument based on another document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I was wondering if it's possible in `Mongoose` to have a subdocument based on another document.

Normally I would do something like this:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CountrySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    info: String,
    cities : [
        {
            type: Schema.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'Ressource'
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Country', CountrySchema);
```

this however create a new document and then references it via the `id` to the `country` document. This is not what I want, I want the `resource` document to be nested inside the `country` document. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this fixed my problem:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ressourceSchema = require('../ressource/ressource.model');

var CountrySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    info: String,
    cities : [
        ressourceSchema.schema
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Country', CountrySchema);
```